# FQL Query get Fan Page name via Fan page ID returns null

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Suddenly, the FQL Query does not work, I have this code for so many months and kept it running, now it doesn't work, even my past projects that has this code malfunctioned.

For example,
I have a fan page name called **Sample Page One** and it has the id of **540109632726307**

So, I want to do is, retrieve the **name of the fan page** using the fan page id.

***Query***

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+name+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id=540109632726307
```

***Code***

```
$fbp_id = 540109632726307; //Sample FB ID

$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.'fql?q=SELECT+name+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id= '.$fbp_id.'';
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

var_dump($json_output);
```

When I run the code, it results to **NULL**, it wasn't like that before. Did facebook updates the fql query thing? I can't also seem to find any news about it.

But when I run this link to the browser,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+name+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id=540109632726307
```

It displays the result of the fql query that I made

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Sample Page One"
      }
   ]
}
```

It's a valid url. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things-

1. Define `fb_id` as:

   ```
   $fbp_id = "540109632726307"
   ```

   (since its a big integer)
2. Leave no space after **`=`** in :

   ```
   page_id= '.$fbp_id
   ```
3. There's no variable `$json_output`, use `$fql_query_obj` in `var_dump` instead.

So your code will look like:

```
$fbp_id = "540109632726307"; //Sample FB ID
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.'fql?q=SELECT+name+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id='.$fbp_id.'';
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

var_dump($fql_query_obj);
```

Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Why the concatenation of two strings in $fql_query_url? It could be just one string.
You also do not need to concatenate the single quotes at the end.

Did you try to get the file via the api.facebook.com url?

e.g.

```
$fbp_id = "540109632726307"; //Sample FB ID
$fql_query_url = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+name+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id='.$fbp_id;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
var_dump($fql_query_obj);
```

Facebook is very inconsequent. Sometimes things work with graph.facebook.com and sometimes you need to use api.facebook.com.